# React reload on save stop working when editing index.js file

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

I'm new to React so be patient with me plz.
I'm trying to learn React where I faced the first issue.
I Created a new React app project using

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

I got a fresh new project with some basics.
When I start the dev server with

```
npm start
```

Everything works correctly.
Now the problem is whenever I do some changes to **`index.js`** file, auto reload on save stops working
and I have to restart the dev server to make it work again. It doesn't happen if I make any changes in other files like components, CSS file or any other files. It just happens when I made any change to **`index.js`** file. So how can I solve this issue because it's so annoying to restart server after any changes in the file.

npm version: 6.14.8.

node version: 14.15.0.

OS: Widnows 10.

Text editor: VSCode

Excuse my bad English.